# How to get User Input to Populate Jira Fields

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin

I am new to Java and using the JIRA MISC Custom Fields add-on and require some logic assistance to solve math functions between two drop down fields.

Field one is "User Cost"
This field contains four string selections with the user price posted at the end of the string.

1. sam costs .21
2. mitch costs .419
3. Lance costs 2.66
4. xmen costs 13.338

Field two is "Usage"
This field contains two string selections:

1. 24 hours (unless maintenance)
2. 12 Hours (7a-7p)

The argument should be invoked into a new field called "Total User Cost."  This field would automatically display the correct price for user and usage amount.

The equation blueprint would be as follows:

```
Cost*31(calendar days)*usage(12 || 24)
```

I would want my form to update based on user input selection of these two fields and other variables in my equation.

This is what I have so far:

[[image: instance]]

[image: usage]

Thank you in advance for any feedback!

Comment: Looks like `issue` doesn't have a value or can't be resolved

Comment: And if `issue.get("X")` is supposed to return some value, then why are you overriding all your variables on the following lines?

Comment: I am overriding the value because the value returned is a String, and I need a double to be returned so I can finish the equation

Comment: But Java is a statically typed language. You have red lines under your values because you have not defined, `userSam`, for example, as a `String userSam = issue.get("X")`. And you can't assign a double value to a `String` object.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you first need to initialize `issue` to something. (It looks red in your images like that variable doesn't exist)

Then, you can do something like this

```
double costSam = 0.21;
String userSam = issue.get("customfield_10620");
```

Then, if you are needing to convert or otherwise do some math on `userSam`, then you need this

```
double samTotal = costSam * Double.parseDouble(userSam);
```

---

Some flaws with your code

1. You have to define types for your values like `String` or `double`.
2. If you have `String x = "hello"` on one line, then `x = 0.4` on the next, that won't work because of incompatible types
3. If you did have compatible types on consecutive lines, then the first line is pointless unless using the value from the first, as the second line overwrites the value of the first one

Comment: I'm not sure if I can assign issue to something, because issue is a reference to my customfieldID in Jira which would then give me unique customfieldvalueKey assigned to one of the drop down selections.

ie. sam costs .21
    mitch costs .419

But i'll try to use your input and let you know what happens

Comment: You have to assign the variable `issue` to something. Otherwise, `issue.get` doesn't make sense

Comment: this is from the plugin website:
https://innovalog.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JMCF/JIRA+Misc+Custom+Fields#JIRAMiscCustomFields-calculatedtextfield

Comment: Alright, well, Java is Java, so if you think you already have a `issue` variable that is assigned, then fine.